# How to check if Samba is installed

Tags: samba, services, smb

I don't know if Samba is pre-installed in my Linux system.

I have the `/etc/samba/` directory, with `smb.conf` file. But if I try one of these commands

```
sudo service smb start
sudo service samba start
sudo service smbd start
```

the answer is always `unrecognized service`.

In `/etc/init.d` there is no file like `smb`, `samba` or `smbd`. How could I check anymore?

Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easier way is to check with your package manager. dpkg, yum, emerge, etc. If that doesn't work, you just need to type `samba --version` and if it's in your path it should work. Lastly you can use `find / -executable -name samba` to find any executable named samba. If those test are negative, is highly probable that you don't have samba installed.

Comment: The commands relevant for the current Fedora release (25) are `rpm --query samba`, `dnf list installed samba`, `smbd --version`, and `find /usr/sbin/ -executable -name smbd`. The command to check the service is `systemctl status smb`.

Answer (score 6):

In SMB version 4.11.6-Ubuntu, run the following command:

```
systemctl status smbd
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative and suitable way. Note that `sudo` is not necessary.

Comment: `sudo` is not required.

Comment: @user311086 It's funny that I can't edit your answer as it requires changing more than 6 characters and removing `sudo ` is just 5 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use the smbstatus command

you see below.
version 3.6.23-14.el6_6
and status of you samba process and user, group etc...

Comment: Can you give some example, recommendations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is an even easier way to check for installed programs. You can check for any installed program by typing:

~$ which [program]

So in this case

~$ which samba

If it is installed, it gives you the location of it. If it isn't, you get an empty output.

Comment: That won't work in this case as there's no file named `samba`. `which smbd` would show if the server is installed -- but only if `/usr/sbin` is in the user's PATH.